# Javascript: Do animation on scroll

Tags: javascript, html

I have simple code where animation start when page is loaded. Is there any option how to do animation start when I scrolled on this div?

```js
$('.count').each(function () {
    $(this).prop('Counter',0).animate({
        Counter: $(this).text()
    }, {
        duration: 3000,
        easing: 'swing',
        step: function (now) {
            $(this).text(Math.ceil(now));
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="shiva"><span class="count">200</span></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is your solution!

```js
$('#shiva').bind('mousewheel', function() {
  $('.count').each(function() {
    $(this).prop('Counter', 0).animate({
      Counter: $(this).text()
    }, {
      duration: 3000,
      easing: 'swing',
      step: function(now) {
        $(this).text(Math.ceil(now));
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="shiva"><span class="count">200</span></div>
```

This will bind the 'mousewheel' moved event to the #shiva outer div, such that when a user scrolls, your JQuery function will start!

Comment: Hey, this works on JS Fiddle & in the Stack Overflow Snippet runner. It implies there's something else wrong with your code. Have you provided your entire solution? (There might be something else going on).

Comment: Also, hit f12 in your browser and tell me if your page has any errors?

Answer (score 0):

Calculate distance between window and element, using onscroll event:

```js
$(window).on('scroll',function () {
    $('.count').each(function () {
        var wst=$(window).scrollTop();
        var wh=$(window).height();
        var dot=$(this).offset().top;
        var dh=$(this).height();
        if((dot-wst>0)&&(dot-wst<=wh-dh)&&(!$(this).hasClass("animate-complete"))){
            $(this).addClass("animate-complete");
            $(this).prop('Counter',0).animate({
                Counter: $(this).text()
            }, {
                duration: 3000,
                easing: 'swing',
                step: function (now) {
                    $(this).text(Math.ceil(now));
                }
            });
         }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<div id="shiva"><span class="count">200</span></div>
```